# Spark/Scala group similar words and count

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, scala-collections

I am trying to group and count words in an rdd such that if a word ends with s/ly it is counted as the same word.

```
hi
yes
love
know
hi
knows
loves
lovely
```

Expected output:

```
hi 2
yes 1
love 3
know 2
```

This is what I currently have:

```
data.map(word=>(word,1)).reduceByKey((a,b)=>(a+b+).collect
```

Any help is appreciated regarding adding s/ly condition.

Comment: Actually, your question is ambiguous. If a word ends with s or ly, it should be counted as the exact word without s or ly? e.g. lovely should be counted as love?

Comment: Added expected output

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to count stem of words in your input list. The process of finding the stem of a word in Computational Linguistics is called stemming. If your goal is to handle s and ly at the end of the words in your input list, you can remove in a map step and then count the remaining parts. As a matter of fact, there would be some side effects by removing s and ly blindly. For instance, if there is a word which ends with s like "is" you would count "i" at the end. It's a better solution to use some available stemmers like Porter or the one which is available in Stanford Corenlp.

```
listRdd.mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2(t.replayAll("(ly|s)$", ""), 1))
.reduceByKey((a,b) -> a+b).collect()
```

the second solution which can help to overcome other suffixes too is using stemmers:

```
listRdd.mapToPair(t -> {
        Stemmer stemmer = new Stemmer();
        return new Tuple2(stemmer.stem(t), 1));
}).reduceByKey((a,b) -> a+b).collect();
```

about stemmer can be replaced with any implementation of stemmers. 
For more information about stemmers and lemmatizers, you can use https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group together words that finish with 's' or 'ly' here is how I would do it:

```
data
  .map(word => (if (word.endsWith('s') || word.endsWith('ly')) 's/ly-words' else word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_+_)
  .collect
```

If you want to separate 'ly' words from 's' words from the rest:

```
data
  .map(word => (if (word.endsWith('s')) 's-words' else if (word.endsWith('ly')) 'ly-words' else word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_+_)
  .collect
```

If you want to count words that end with 'ly' or 's' as if they did not end with it (eg. 'love', 'lovely', 'loves' are counted as being 'love'):

```
data
  .map(word => (if (word.endsWith('s')) word.slice(0, word.length-1) else if (word.endsWith('ly')) word.slice(0, word.length-2) else word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_+_)
  .collect
```